# jQuery function not started

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a weird problem. I have a freight calculation field to be executed if the User deletes a digit input , I hide one content. While running the script in chrome console, it is loaded, but when using the call in html, js it does not run. This is what I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/diasbass/u3xr0921/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#btnFreteSimulacao").click(function() {
        $("#txtCep").keyup(function() {
            if ($("#txtCep").val()) {
                $('p.montagem').hide();
            } else {
                $('p.montagem').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to click the button to enabled the keyup handler on the input. Is this intentional? What's the desired behavior?

Comment: working fine in jsfiddle. just remember to include jQuery. Anyway, you shouldn't bind a keyup event every time the user clicks the button.

Comment: This appears to be working just fine.  In what way is it not working for you?  I go to your jsFiddle, click the button, and then enter/remove keystrokes in the input.  The content hides/shows accordingly.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyup` event handler is inside the click function, probably it is of no use.

Also need to check `$("#txtCep").val().length` for showing and hiding the `p.montagem`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $("#txtCep").keyup(function() {         
                if($("#txtCep").val().length ==0) {
                    $('p.montagem').hide();             
                } else {
                    $('p.montagem').show();
                }
            });     

    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3xr0921/6/)

Comment: An empty string also evaluates to false in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you ! I had not realized it . Now it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are mixing two asynchronous events 1) Button click 2) Input keyup. Your code expects to work when both are happening same time. I would suggest remove dependency on one event. Like below.

```
    $( "#btnFreteSimulacao" ).click(function() {                
       // $("#txtCep").keyup(function() {         
            if($("#txtCep").val()) {
                $('p.montagem').hide();             
            } else {
                $('p.montagem').show();
            }
        });     
   // });
    });
```

If thats not possible, try to look towards promises.

Comment: Thank you ! I had not realized it . Now it worked properly.